# Angular view is blank of object that return of a $http.get request

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-ui-router

I'm getting data object from a API via $http.get(). This is my angular controller:

```js
angular.module('supernovaWebApp',['ui.router'])
  .controller('professoresCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/instructors/"+instructorId).success(function(data,status){
          console.log(data);
          $scope.professor = data;        
        });
      };
  }])
  .config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('instructor', {
      url: '/instructor',
      templateUrl: 'views/instructor.html',
      controller: 'professoresCtrl'
    });
  });
```

The object returns without errors and a can see it in the webbrowser console, but no info is showed in the view.

```html
<div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <div  class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{professor.name}} {{professor.last_name}}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <p>{{professor.profession}}</p>
        <i class="material-icons md-18">phone</i> {{professor.phone}}
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__menu">
        <button ng-click="delInstructor(instructor)" class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
          <i id="btn-archive" class="material-icons" >clear</i>
          <span class="mdl-tooltip" data-mdl-for="btn-archive">
            Arquivar
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

The bizare thing is that this code works when I get an array of objects and use ng-repeat to show then. I search for some issues, but can´t find the solution. What am I missing? Please can you help me. I'm stucked.

Print of the console. The object that appear correctly is that one with id:1.
[Console print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IERx6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK093.png)

When I do the same thing to get more than one object from database, it works. Here is the similar code.

```js
angular.module('supernovaWebApp',['ui.router'])
  .controller('professoresCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
      
      var getInstructors = function(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/instructors").success(function(data,status){
          console.log(data);
          $scope.instructors = data;
        });
      };
    getInstructors();
  }])
  .config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('instructors',{
      url: '/instructors',
      templateUrl: 'views/instructors.html',
      controller: 'professoresCtrl'
    });
  });
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="instructor in instructors">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <div  class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{instructor.name}} {{instructor.last_name}}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <p>{{instructor.profession}}</p>
        <i class="material-icons md-18">phone</i> {{instructor.phone}}
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a ui-sref="instructor" ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="getInstructor(instructor.id)" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          Veja mais!
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__menu">
        <button ng-click="delInstructor(instructor)" class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
          <i id="btn-archive" class="material-icons" >clear</i>
          <span class="mdl-tooltip" data-mdl-for="btn-archive">
            Arquivar
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add what the `console.log(data)` prints out?

Comment: @Fissio I added the print of the console.

Comment: Just to make sure: The "instructor" $scope variable is written correct? the `$scope.instructors` on the $http success is just a type, i guess

Comment: It's written correctly @Watte. I don't know what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated after Fissio commented**

The depreciated `$http.get(..).success()` has a different signature than the newer `$http.get(..).then(...)` which is working with promises. So `$scope.professor = data` is the old way of `$scope.professor = data.data`

**Old Answer**

$http returns a response object. Your actual data is in "response.data". So you're using `$scope.professor = data;` where it should be `$scope.professor = data.data`. Although this does not explain the correct behaviour on arrays..

Comment: He's using the deprecated `.success(function(data, status, headers, config) { ... })` function, so the actual data is in the `data`, not `data.data`

Comment: Oh, thought the deprecated `success` had the same signature. Will update the answer. Thanks Fissio!

Comment: I changed to the $http.then way, the view is blank yet and the console now appears the the object response, with headers, status, data... No errors! if I use $scope.professor = response.data got nothing appearing in the view. Do you think this should be any issue with data bind?

Comment: I added one thing that works, that is always the same thing but when I get an array as a response callback.